# storing username/email and password with a hash of the hash of the email/password?

Tags: passwords, password-management

Quite the simple discussion this one (one would assume):

If I'd hash the email and password, and then hash the hashes, whould this be considered safe enough or would this just be a waste considering you could just salt them both?

What should the salt be, could it be the username-part of the email?

Answer (score 2):

Don't hash the usernames. For passwords, hash them using something like [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). Read [this](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) ASAP for more (also contains example source code).